# How to evaluate this sum? $ \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{12^k}{(4^k - 3^k)(4^{k+1} - 3^{k+1})} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to solve this exercise?

> Evaluate
> $$
> \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{12^k}{(4^k - 3^k)(4^{k+1} - 3^{k+1})}
> $$

[image: my attempt]

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make posts more readable.

Comment: okay i'll take care

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. This ain't a homework solving site.

Comment: Hint: write [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2593662/decomposing-a-particular-fraction/2593783) for $\,z=\frac{3}{4}\,$ and see what you get.

Comment: You have just reposted your previous question - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2599830/how-to-solve-this-summation I merged them.

Comment: Oh great ! You saved my life !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As expected the series telescopes and therefore can be readily summed.

From a partial fraction decomposition we have
$$\frac{1}{(4^k - 3^k)(4^{k + 1} - 3^{k + 1})} = \frac{3^{-k}}{4^k - 3^k} - \frac{4 \cdot 3^{-k}}{4^{k + 1} - 3^{k + 1}}.$$
Thus the sum becomes
$$S = \sum_{k = 1}^n \left (\frac{4^k}{4^k - 3^k} - \frac{4^{k + 1}}{4^{k + 1} - 3^{k + 1}} \right ) = \frac{4^1}{4^1 - 3^1} - \frac{4^{n + 1}}{4^{n + 1} - 3^{n + 1}} = 4 - \frac{4^{n + 1}}{4^{n + 1} - 3^{n + 1}}.$$

---

**Update**

The partial fraction decomposition can be done as follows. Let $a = 4^k$ and $b = 3^k$. Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{12^k}{(4^k - 3^k)(4^{k + 1} - 3^{k + 1})} &= \frac{4^k \cdot 3^k}{(4^k - 3^k)(4 \cdot 4^{k} - 3 \cdot 3^{k})}\\
&= \frac{ab}{(a - b)(4a - 3b)}\\
&= \frac{a}{a - b} - \frac{4a}{4a - 3b}\\
&= \frac{4^k}{4^k - 3^k} - \frac{4^{k + 1}}{4^{k + 1} - 3^{k + 1}}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Hey..there was a 12^k term in the numerator also ..you missed it ?

Comment: And please elaborate the first step

Comment: Notice that $12^k = 4^k \cdot 3^k$ meaning the $3^k$ term cancels on multiplication of $12^k$ with the partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: @Shashank Shekhar - Have updated my post showing how the partial fraction decomposition can be found.

Answer (score 1):

You were close. You should write $$12^k=[(4^{k+1}-3^{k+1})-4(4^k-3^k)]\cdot[(4^{k+1}-3^{k+1})-3(4^k-3^k)]$$

Comment: What should be done next ? @AbishankaSaha

Comment: After the merge by @JackD'Aurizio, this answer (Jan 9) to the question (Jan 10) is incomprehensible because this hint is redundant with the beginning of the OP's attempt.